# JSON parameter is like nothing I have seen

Tags: java, json

I'm working on some JSON converting to POJO and the server I'm getting response of is sending a JSON like this:

```
"Availability":{
                "StatusCode":"A",
                "BreakDown":{
                            "2017-10-27":"A"
                            }
               }
```

How can I save this ( `"2017-10-27":"A"` )? It changes with each of my request so it should be dynamic! Is it even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic ?

Comment: There should be any way to get the keys of an array.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are going the value currently represented as `"2017-10-27":"A"`, you have to know it is hold in the variable `"BreakDown"`. So you need to query this variable with jsonPath: `$.Availability.BreakDown`.

it will give this JSON object:

```
{"2017-10-27":"A"}
```

Hope it answer your question

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is pretty accurate but to extract the key and value without directly referencing is the target since they are dynamic.

```
var x = obj.Availability.Breakdown;
for(var key in x){
    console.log(key);
    console.log(x[key]);
}
```

This way you get the key and the value both and use it as you like.
Plus, if there are multiple key-value pair inside var x then they can also be reached with this loop.

Comment: The question is tagged `java`, not sure if your answer is really applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that with **"should be dynamic"** you mean that the content that you want to save (the one inside BreakDown) could change (even the type) for each request and assuming that your example of the json is:

***Test.json:***

```
{
  "StatusCode":"A",
  "BreakDown":{
    "2017-10-27":"A"
  }
}
```

You could use the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library to get the info that you want. Because every class has Object as a superclass, you could deserialize your json as a `Map<Object, Object>`.

```
public static void main(String args[])  {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Map<Object, Object> breakDown=null;

        String filename="/.../Test.json";
        JsonReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Object,Object>>() {}.getType();
        Map <Object,Object> conv= gson.fromJson(reader, type);

        for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : conv.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            if(entry.getKey().equals("BreakDown"))
            {
               breakDown= (Map<Object, Object>) entry.getValue();
            }
        }

        if(breakDown!=null){
            Map.Entry first= breakDown.entrySet().iterator().next();
            System.out.println(first.getKey());
            System.out.println(first.getValue());
        }
    }
```

The `Map<Object, Object> breakDown` map is also of Objects because I'm assuming that the key and the value could be different of the example that you posted. Otherwise, if the key is always a date and the value a string, can be defined as `Map<Date, String> breakDown`.